# Launch PowerShell script on remote server using Talend

Tags: powershell, talend

I'm using a Talend job located on a server A , and I'm trying to runa PowerShell script with it.
my problem : the PS Script is located on remote server B.

I've managed to run the script from server A using the 'Tsystem' component but the PS Script is running on server A context. 
I think the 'tsystem' component is getting the PS script from server B but runsit in server A.

Is there a way to runa powershell script on remote server using Talend ?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance,

Antoine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

of course - it is tSSH component

you must be sure - firewall is no block 22 port connection, and in case if (thought - yes) remote server is Windows, ssh service installed and enabled (it support native with Windows Server and many 3rd party servers available)

Comment: Hi a_vlad, Thank you very much for your answer ! I will test it and tell you about it when it's done.